# Cannot implicitly convert class into ArrayList

Tags: c#

I am starting to learn c# and I came across this error

> Cannot convert implicitly convert Animal into
>   System.Collections.ArrayList

This is the code

```
 private Animal adoptedPets;
 public Animal AdoptedPets
 {  
        get { return adoptedPets;}
        set  {adoptedPets = value;}
 }
```

I am trying to set a list of `Animals` to this property of my object. I tried to cast my list like that `(ArrayList) adoptedPets`, but it didn't work and gave me the above error.

Comment: but how?? adoptedPets returns 1 animal... why should that be castable to a list?

Comment: Given code is not enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think the problem occurs when you were trying to set AdoptedPets property with a value, and your code snippet doesn't seem to has any problem.

Comment: The problem is that converting an Animal to an ArrayList just does not make any sense. Thus, you need to tell us **why** you want to do that, so that we can help you solve your **underlying problem**.

Comment: How should one *single* element be transformed into a list? You can *add* a single element to a list. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: How is `Animal` defined?

Comment: @Alen : In addition to what is asked in the comments, you should also give the code that actually causes your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `adoptedPets` to be a `List<Animal>` and not just a single `Animal`, you should declare it as such. Best would be to declare it a s

```
 private IList<Animal> adoptedPets;
 public IList<Animal> AdoptedPets
 {  
        get { return adoptedPets;}
        set  {adoptedPets = value;}
 }
```

Note the `IList`instead of `List`. You could also use `IEnumerable`. It is a good pracice so that any kind of list can be assigned.

Now, I am assuming that you *want* your `adoptedPets` to store a list of `Animal`s . But you are not precise at all in your question.

Comment: Can't vote yet, not enough rep. I edited the question anyway.